# CSS Fixed column width before wrap and full width after wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, multiple-columns

**What I need**
[image: layout]

Look at the image for a general idea of what I need. I am **avoiding media queries** as I have a sidebar on my page which pushes all the main content, which then makes @media queries terrible to work with. I wish container queries was a thing, but I'll have to stick with creating more dynamic css than using a buggy polyfill.

**What I have (don't laugh)**
This is what I have worked out so far:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; /* a wrapping flexbox */
}

.content {
  background: cyan;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  background: tomato;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child sidebar">1</div>
  <div class="child content">2</div>
</div>
```

It's pretty much not working at all

I don't need it to be flexbox, it can be grid aswell...

Comment: Sorry but you are going to need media queries here. Trying to avoid them is not using a vital component of CSS

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think you understood my problem with media queries. I have a sidebar on my website which doesn't overlay the mian content, but it pushes it such that the main content gets less wide. The media query uses the viewport size, so the main content would not change responsiveness if you were to expand the sidebar. That is why I would need container queries.

Answer (score 4):

There is a scenerio that you can do that we make our .container `max-width:1000px;` than we gave

.red `flex-grow:3`

.blue  `flex-grow:7`

So when they split 1000px together .red will take 300px (`flex-grow:3`) and .blue will take 700px (`flex-grow:7`).

After 600px when they both reach their `min-width:300px` row wrap will happen and they will grow whole container.

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  
}


.container {
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  height: 15rem;
}

.red {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width:300px;
}

.blue {
  background: cyan;
  min-width: 500px;
  flex-grow: 7;
  width:400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
  .container{
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I notice now that it doesn't follow the rule that the max width of the container shall be 400px only when it has wrapped, before the wrap it shall have a width of 100%

Comment: I edit the code change .blue `min-width:100px` so red will always stay 300px and when screen in 400px which in that time blue will be 100px, row wrap will happen. @MagnusEnebakk

Comment: Ah, yes it's way closer to what I need! The only problem now is that it is not wrapping before the blue is 100px. I want it to wrap when the blue is like 500px and then after the wrap, it goes to 400px as max and 300px as min... (The entire container should be 400px max and 300px min after the wrap) Is this possible without queries?

Comment: I dont understand,  what do you mean when blue is 500px wrap ?

Comment: This is all a video player, the blue area is a video and the red is a sidebar where you can use various controls. I want the control panel to go below the video when the video width gets smaller than 500px. BUT, after the wrap and the control panel is below the video, I want the max width of the entire container to be 400px, and min 300px.  Here is an image: https://imgur.com/a/i4gKlr1

Comment: Okay i understand what did you mean.  Problem is we set .blue `min-width:500px`  then we wrap them and in this sitaution we can not set a new width to blue without a media query

Comment: Edit the code it is the best we can get :D